# React Routes problem with Tags other than Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using `"react-router-dom": "^5.3.2"`

In my component I have the following code:

```
render() {
  return <div role="main">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth" exact component={Auth} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={() => <>Main page</>} />

      <IsGranted for={[ 'superuser' ]}>
        <PrivateRoute path="/servers" exact component={ServerList} />
      </IsGranted>
  
      {/* or even nested in a <></> */}

      <Route component={_ => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component:Component, ...rest }) => 
  <Route {...rest} render={props => isAuthenticated() ? <Component {...props}/> : <Redirect to={{ pathname:'/auth', state:{ from:props.location } }}/> }/>

const IfGranted = ({ children }) => condition() ? children : null
```

The problem is, everything below the empty tag `<>` is ignored.

For example, I expect `Not found` be rendered, if I type in some gibberish in the URL.
That happens only, if the `<>...</>` is commented out.

Is there anything I can do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only valid children of the `Switch` component are the `Route` component (*including custom route components*) and the `Redirect` component. `React.Fragment` breaks this abstraction. The `Switch` component returns the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location ***or*** in the case where a child component is neither, *that* child is returned and nothing below it is reachable, i.e. the "Not Found" route.

From what I see of your snippet there is no need for the `React.Fragment` wrapping the `PrivateRoute` component.

1. Remove the extraneous fragment around the `"/servers"` route.
2. Use the route's `component` prop for React component references, use the `render` prop for inline functions.
3. Order the routes in inverse order by route path specificity, this removes the need to specify the `exact` prop on every route. Since you have a "not found" catch all route, the home path `"/"` above it *will* need the `exact` prop to preclude it from all other generic matching.

Code

```
render() {
  return <div role="main">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/servers" component={ServerList} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" render={() => <>Main page</>} />
      <Route render={() => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
}
```

PrivateRoute

To make the `PrivateRoute` align more with the `Route` component API it should take all the same props as a `Route` and render either a `Route` or `Redirect` component. Use the `useLocation` hook to access the current `location` object for redirect purposes.

Example:

```
const PrivateRoute = props => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return isAuthenticated()
    ? <Route {...props} />
    : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname:'/auth',
          state: { from: location }
        }}
      />
    );
};
```

### Update

To add the ability to use roles to restrict access I would either wrap the routed component directly, or create a Higher Order component, or abstract another `PrivateRolesRoute` component.

- Using wrapper

  ```
   <Switch>
     <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
     <PrivateRoute
       path="/servers"
       render={props => (
         <IsGranted for={['superuser']}>
           <ServerList {...props} />
         </IsGranted>
       )}
     />
     <PrivateRoute exact path="/" render={() => <>Main page</>} />
     <Route render={() => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
   </Switch>
  ```
- Using HOC

  Create a HOC that takes a component to decorate and a roles array, and returns a wrapped component.

  ```
   const withIsGranted = (Component, roles = []) => props => (
     <IsGranted for={roles}>
       <Component {...props} />
     </IsGranted>
   );
  ```

  Decorate the component you want to role protect.

  ```
   export default withIsGranted(ServerList, ['superuser']);
  ```

  Use the exported decorated component in the route. It won't look different than it was previously.

  ```
   <Switch>
     <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
     <PrivateRoute path="/servers" component={ServerList} />
     <PrivateRoute exact path="/" render={() => <>Main page</>} />
     <Route render={() => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
   </Switch>
  ```
- Using `PrivateRolesRoute` route component

  Create a new private route component that takes additional props and handles the conditional rendering of the protected route.

  ```
   const PrivateRolesRoute = ({ roles = [], ...props }) => {
     const location = useLocation();

     return isAuthenticated()
       ? (
         <IsGranted for={roles}>
           <Route {...props} />
         </IsGranted>
       )
       : (
         <Redirect
           to={{
             pathname:'/auth',
             state: { from: location }
           }}
         />
       );
   };
  ```

  Use the new `PrivateRoleRoute` and pass the `roles` prop.

  ```
   <Switch>
     <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
     <PrivateRoleRoute
       path="/servers"
       component={ServerList}
       roles={['superuser']}
     />
     <PrivateRoute exact path="/" render={() => <>Main page</>} />
     <Route render={() => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
   </Switch>
  ```

Comment: Of course, I put an empty fragment for demo. I actually use some conditional tags to make the `/servers`-Route available only to some specific role.

Comment: @injecteer Please see my updated answer. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Yeah, it's rather disappointing, that Routes behaves this way...
I was about to implement the role-check in `PrivateRoute`, which is the lesser of all evils